# Button not center aligning within div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally center align a button at the bottom of the div. I read some posts and they all suggest using text-align:center; on the parent div, but that isn't working for me.

CSS:

```
  .col-lg-3{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .btn-primary{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
```

HTML:

```
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h1 class="display-6">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p class="text">123456789</p>
            <button onclick="window.location.href='projects/test.html'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:0 auto;display:block;">Learn More</button>
          </div>
```

When I run this code the button is at the bottom of the div, but isn't center aligned.
Could anyone help me out with this?

Thank You

Comment: Just remove `position: absolute;` The button will be centered by the `text-align: center` of its parent. Unless there is other CSS you have not included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's `position: absolute;` for position absolute you have to do like below:

```
.btn-primary{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

**NOTE:** If the height of the parent div is `auto` and it's changing with the content you don't need `position: absolute;` just remove `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`

Comment: Is there another way to do it, I am trying to keep my css as small as possible.

Comment: you can simplify margin to margin: 0 auto 0 auto; which is margin: top right bottom left; but that's all if you want to keep position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to remove `position: absolute`, which requires setting `left` and `right` to center. This is not necessary since the button will be centered with the `text-align: center` CSS of the parent. This is plenty to horizontally center.

```
 .col-lg-3{
    text-align: center;
 }
```

[Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/ve0qgskp/)

[image]

Comment: So I removed position:absolute; and now the button is in the center but it isn't at the bottom of the div. How do I fix this?

Comment: @ShalajWadhwa it is at the bottom. You can see in the screenshot I just added that this is the case.